# Azure add load balanced port

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to add load balanced port 443 and port 80 to my virtual machines, and when I do it, I keep getting the following error:

```
The probe setting for the endpoint group webSecure-443 is null. An external endpoint webSHTTP cannot specify a probe setting.
```

It didn't do this back in August and September of last year when I setup the servers, now I'm doing some updating and obviously things have changed.  Any thoughts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The port changes are being made through portal.  This was working before, why wouldn't it now?

Comment: It would help if you showed how you're adding the ports: Portal? PowerShell? CLI? And if PowerShell/CLI, the actual script call you're making.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Through the portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior for creating an endpoint via the portal has changed in the past few months. Try deleting the original endpoint and creating it again before you attempt to add additional endpoints for load-balancing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tabrez answer, I think you will have to recreate the endpoints.  check the following link it might be helpful http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/how-to-load-balance-virtual-machines